# Set different types of img to a specific height

Tags: javascript, html, css, image

I'm making a website and I would like to have images with different height and width to be centered in the page. There is a script so we only see one image at a time.

I thought about creating a div that occupy the whole page, but then I can't find a way to force the image to be centered inside it.

Some advice?
This is what I got for now:

```js
var slideIndex = 1;
showDivs(slideIndex);

function plusDivs(n) {
  showDivs(slideIndex += n);
}

function showDivs(n) {
  var i;
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  if (n > x.length) {
    slideIndex = 1
  }
  if (n < 1) {
    slideIndex = x.length
  }
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    x[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  x[slideIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
}
```

```css
body {
  background-color: black;
}

div>div {
  background-color: blue;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.imagetest1 {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>La chasse</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="w3-content w3-display-container">
    <div class="mySlides"><img class="imagetest1" src="img_lights.jpg"></div>
    <div class="mySlides"><img class="imagetest1" src="img_lights.jpg"></div>

    <button class="w3-button w3-black w3-display-left" onclick="plusDivs(-1)">&#10094;</button>
    <button class="w3-button w3-black w3-display-right" onclick="plusDivs(1)">&#10095;</button>
</body>

</html>
```

Thanks for your help!
Mateo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your outside div to this:

`<div class="w3-content w3-display-container w3-display-middle>`

And in your CSS add the following:

`div.w3-content { height: 100%; width: 100%; }`

Also add `object-fit: contain;` to `.imagetest1`

Answer (score 0):

Normally centering of an image is done like this:

```
img{
   display:block;
   margin:auto auto;
}
```

You will need to ensure the parent element has been properly sized first.

Answer (score 0):

Also, by using bootstrap 4.1 (which I would highly recommend learning) you could just do the following:

```
<img class="mx-auto">
```

Link to bootstrap: https://getbootstrap.com/

If you don't want to use bootstrap, the w3 css you are using also has properties to align objects, you can read about that [here](https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/w3css_display.asp).